# C# CRM QueryExpression LinkEntity join via multiple field

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

Is it possible to join multiple fields dynamically in CRM?

What I mean is something like this in SQL

```
select field1, field2, ..., fieldN
from ServiceAppointment
inner join bh_product
on bh_product.bh_contract = ServiceAppointment.bh_product.bh_contract
and bh_product.serviceid = ServiceAppointment.serviceid
```

I'm trying to come-up with something above using queryexpression but I'm not getting the desired behavior I want and I end having LOTS of records than expected. I can do this if I KNOW before hand the value of field number 2, but what at runtime I don't know and the query has to join 2 fields. My actual code is below, minus the part that I can't come up with.

This doesn't work... I'm expecting only 2 records but I get hundreds...

```
var leContact = new LinkEntity(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName, ActivityParty.EntityLogicalName, "activityid", "activityid", JoinOperator.Inner);
leContact.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();
leContact.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, contactId);
queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(leContact);
result = GetServiceActivityList(queryExpression);

var leService = new LinkEntity(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName, BrightHorizons.Shared.CRM.Interface.Service.EntityLogicalName, "serviceid", "serviceid", JoinOperator.Inner);
queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(leService);
result = GetServiceActivityList(queryExpression);

// THIS IS THE PROBLEM    
    var leProduct = new LinkEntity(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName, bh_product.EntityLogicalName, "bh_contract", "bh_contract", JoinOperator.Inner);
    var leProduct2 = new LinkEntity(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName, bh_product.EntityLogicalName, "serviceid", "bh_service", JoinOperator.Inner);
    queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(leProduct2);
    queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(leProduct);
    result = GetServiceActivityList(queryExpression);

//THIS ALSO DOESNT WORK 
    var leProduct = new LinkEntity(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName, bh_product.EntityLogicalName, "bh_contract", "bh_contract", JoinOperator.Inner);
    leProduct.AddLink(bh_product.EntityLogicalName, "bh_service", "bh_service", JoinOperator.Inner);
    queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(leProduct);
    result = GetServiceActivityList(queryExpression);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you looked into it, but joins are really easy in Linq ([msdn examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx)).  I've written Contact-Accounts joins like this:

```
var appContacts = (
from c in ctx.contacts
join a in ctx.accounts on c.contactid equals a.primarycontactid
where a.name.Contains("Contoso")
select new { c.contactid, c.fullname }).ToList());
```

There's [a good thread on N:N over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097921/crm-2011-nn-many-to-many-linq-issue).

Comment: It's not possible according to this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046711/are-composite-joins-possible-using-fetchxml-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0

Comment: That post says that joins across *multiple* columns are not possible in FetchXML...but are in Linq.  I'm not sure what point you are trying to make?

Comment: See this followup thread and tell me your thoughts :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461457/crm-linq-composite-join-the-method-join-is-not-supported-error

Comment: The answerer points out that a Linq provider can implement a subset of functionality.  That is the case for the CRM Linq provider.  The MSDN examples I linked to provide a list of ways you can use the Linq for CRM.