# CRM LINQ Composite join "The method 'Join' is not supported" error

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm

Im getting a "The method 'Join' is not supported" error... Funny thing is that i simply converted the 1st LINQ into the 2nd version and it doesnt work...

What i wanted to have was LINQ version #3, but it also doesnt work...

---

This works

```
var query_join9 = from s in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName)
join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(bh_product.EntityLogicalName)
on s["bh_contract"] equals b["bh_contract"]
where ((EntityReference)s["bh_contract"]).Id == Guid.Parse("09BDD5A9-BBAF-E111-A06E-0050568B1372")
select new
{
Events = s,
Products = b
};
```

This doesn't

```
var query_join9 = from s in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName)
join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(bh_product.EntityLogicalName)
on new { contractid = s["bh_contract"] }
equals new { contractid = b["bh_contract"] }
where ((EntityReference)s["bh_contract"]).Id == Guid.Parse("09BDD5A9-BBAF-E111-A06E-0050568B1372")
select new
{
Events = s,
Products = b
};
```

Also, this doesn't, which is a composite join and what i really aim for

```
var query_join9 = from s in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(ServiceAppointment.EntityLogicalName)
join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery(bh_product.EntityLogicalName)
on new { contractid = s["bh_contract"], serviceid = s["serviceid"] }
equals new { contractid = b["bh_contract"], serviceid = s["serviceid"] }
where ((EntityReference)s["bh_contract"]).Id == Guid.Parse("09BDD5A9-BBAF-E111-A06E-0050568B1372")
select new
{
Events = s,
Products = b
};
```

I tried early binding and still doesnt work...

```
var query_join9 = from s in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery<ServiceAppointment>()
join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery<bh_product>()
on new { foo = s.bh_contract.Id }
equals new { foo = b.bh_Contract.Id }
where s.bh_contract.Id == Guid.Parse("09BDD5A9-BBAF-E111-A06E-0050568B1372")
select new
{
Events = s,
Products = b
};
```

stil not working

```
var query_join9 = from s in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery<ServiceAppointment>()
join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery<bh_product>()
on new { s.bh_contract.Id, s.ServiceId }
equals new { b.bh_Contract.Id, ServiceId = b.bh_Service }
where s.bh_contract.Id == Guid.Parse("09BDD5A9-BBAF-E111-A06E-0050568B1372")
select new
{
Events = s,
Products = b
};
```

---

But im simply trying to do the example(s) here [How to do joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join)

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the 4th sample you've given, can you remove the `new { foo =` and  `}` in the join and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely sure which CRM you're using, I think you're misunderstanding something. 
In order for a LINQ query to work, there needs to be a LINQ provider for the underlying data source -- the bit of code responsible for translating chain of e.g. `Join`, `Where`, operator usage, etc, etc, into the query API of the data source. This might be SQL, some custom query language, or some chain of methods.

Two LINQ providers (such as, one for `LINQ to DataSet` and some custom provider you've written yourself) don't have to support the same methods and other code. The precise subset of LINQ methods (and/or other embedded statements) a LINQ provider supports is dependent on its implementation.

Looking at it like that, it's not that surprising that the LINQ provider you're using doesn't seem to comprehend the standard syntax for joins using multiple fields, or doesn't seem to comprehend the usage of anonymous types at all.

My advice is to search the documentation of the supplied LINQ provider to see which query operations it supports (perhaps there is a note about this specific mode of query not being supported). Failing that, you'll have to resort to some sort of other query -- one not involving an equijoin. Perhaps your best option is to perform the joins separately, and then intersect the two result groups. It really depends on the specifics of the case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx#DoubleJoin).  There are some multiple-column join examples there:

```
using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
{
 var list_join = (from a in svcContext.AccountSet
                  join c in svcContext.ContactSet
                  on a.PrimaryContactId.Id equals c.ContactId
                  where a.Name == "Contoso Ltd" &&     <<--- multiple join here
                  a.Address1_Name == "Contoso Pharmaceuticals"
                  select a).ToList();
 foreach (var c in list_join)
 {
  System.Console.WriteLine("Account " + list_join[0].Name
      + " and it's primary contact "
      + list_join[0].PrimaryContactId.Id);
 }
}
```

[This other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441575/c-sharp-crm-queryexpression-linkentity-join-via-multiple-field/11454892#11454892) might be relevant