# Dynamics CRM: Problem with Composite Key Join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm

I have following query in LINQ to LEFT JOIN same entity:

```
  query = from a in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery("entity1")
            join b in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery("entity1")
            on new { v1 = a["field1"], v2 = a["field2"] } equals new { v1 = b["field2"], v2 = b["field1"] } into gr
            from c_joined in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c_joined["field0"] == null && (a["field1"].Equals(new Guid(@param)) || a["field2"].Equals(new Guid(@param)))
            select a;
```

It complains the following error:

> invalid 'join' condition. an entity member is invoking an invalid
> property or method

I refer from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys

Anything wrong with my `JOIN`? I have no problem if I just use

```
on a["field1"] equals  b["field2"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `new { v1 = a["field1"], v2 = a["field2"] }` construct cannot be resolved to an attribute name.

The LINQ implementation for Dynamics CRM is very limited as it attempts to convert LINQ expressions into `QueryExpression` queries. These queries in turn only implement a basic subset of the SQL language.

When joining two entities make shure that after the `on` the left and right side can be resolved to existing lookup attributes of both entities.

Still keep in mind not all `QueryExpression` capabilities can be used in LINQ queries.

Comment: I read a thread before. It mentioned FetchXml and QueryExpress don't support composite key JOIN, but LINQ does in Dynamic CRM. That's why I use LINQ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046711/are-composite-joins-possible-using-fetchxml-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0

Comment: Ah, I get it. OP of that thread writes he uses LINQ to join the results of two queries. These two resultsets must have been materialized collections, so the join can take full advantage of LINQ for objects. In that case LINQ for CRM is not invoked at all. In your case you are directly joining on the `IQueryable` created on the `OrganizationServiceContext` and that's why LINQ for CRM steps in, with all of its limitations.